# ui-select how to add new options from text in a multiple select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select2, angular-ui-select

I want to add dynamic options retrieved by an angular resource from server but if someone wants to add a new option which is not there in the server typeahead response, then I want to allow the user to enter that text and send that text back to the server

I have this plunkr which uses the angularjs ui-select to add multiple options from dropdown be it a object or just a string

> http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview

But how do I modify it to accept options which are not there in the dropdown?

I am getting data from server like this -

```
var labels = Discussion.get({id:Auth.getCurrentUser()._id},function(){
        for(var i=0;i<labels.labels.length;i++){
            $scope.labels.push({name:labels.labels[i], filter: labels.labels[i].toLowerCase(),color: '#ccc'});
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should put only relevant code in the Plunker not the whole app.

Comment: This plunker is not mine, It is a plunkr on a github repo of `https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select` I found it on google and thought It is a good starting point for my use

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that using ui-select. One good option is to use angular bootstraps's type-ahead. Here is the link https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: but how do I show multiple selected options which are there like in multiple select

Comment: Oh. Then you should look for ngTagsInput. Here is the link: https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput

Comment: It seems that you can achieve this using ui-select too. Check for the attributes tagging and tagging-label  in the documentation of ui-select(https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select)